# Firebase Security rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have data in firebase in following format -

```
  "requests" : {
    "-KpPjt5jQZHBalQRxKSK" : {
      "email" : "pariksheet@agsft.com",
      "itemId" : "-KmazkKp5wavdHOczlDS",
      "quantity" : 1,
      "status" : "new"
    },
    "-KpZsw3KHE9oD1CIFQ4R" : {
      "email" : "pbarapatre@gmail.com",
      "itemId" : "-Kmb-ZXfao7VdfenhfYj",
      "quantity" : 1,
      "status" : "new"
    }
  }
```

Every request contains

```
"email" <- user's email id who has initiated the request.
"itemId" <- id of requested item
"quantity" <- item quantity
"status" <- "new" | "approved" | decline.
```

I am struggling to write Firebase rule which would:

- allow authenticated user to access/read only requests which are raised by him/her.
- allow admin user to read/update all requests.

My current rule is as follows :

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
    "items" : {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "root.child('roles').child(auth.uid).val() === 'admin'"
    },
    "requests": {
        ".write": "root.child('roles').child(auth.uid).val() === 'admin'", /*Only Admins can update request*/
        "$rId": {
            ".read": "data.child('email').val() == auth.email || root.child('roles').child(auth.uid).val() === 'admin'"/*Request owner and admin can only read the particular request*/
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I have maintained separate node roles which has 
    { 
       "uid" : "role" 
    }

I am using AngularFire2 to query Firebase in my app.

Sample code to retrieve requests with given status as below

```
const queryList$ = this.db.list('/requests', {
    query: {
        orderByChild: 'status',
        equalTo: status
    }
})
```

Thanks
Pari

Comment: A lot of this depends on how you implement the concept of *admin users*. Please edit your question to include two code snippets: 1) the minimal code for an operation that should be allowed, 2) the minimal code for an operation that should be disallowed. It also would be good to see your existing (minimal) security rules for the requests.

Comment: Thanks. I have added my existing security rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you make the following changes:

In the root of the database create a new object `admins`

```
"admins": {
    "<ADMIN_1_UID>": "true",
    "<ADMIN_2_UID>": "true"
}
```

Then make changes to your security rules like this:

```
"rules": {
    "admins": {
        ".read": false,
        ".write": false /*This ensures that only from firebase console you can add data to this object*/
    },
    "requests": {
        ".read": "root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).val()",
        ".write": "root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).val()", /*Only Admins can read/update all requests*/
        "$rId": {
            ".read": "data.child('email').val() == auth.email"/*Request owner can read only the particular request*/
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated security rules in original post as per your suggestions now admin is able to write but read is not working both admin and request owner are getting permission denied error. any thoughts?

Comment: Security rules work if I try to read individual request i.e. /requests/req-id  but not if I try to fetch /requests. In this case how do I fetch all requests if I am admin user and fetch subset of requests (own requests) if I am normal user.  Many Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just want to remind you that if you want to execute a search query at `/requests` by a non-admin it will give deny permission since we have given permission only to access particular requests and search queries need the whole parent(`requests`) access.

Comment: Thanks. What would be search query in that case or any alternative you think of. Thanks again

Comment: You could just give read access to whole requests by any auth user and write access only to admin. Or u could change the whole db structure. Depends on what your needs are.