# Firebase Rules Database allow all signed in user to access

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

if i would like to allow all signed in user to access :  
"users/profile/chat" 
How would that look in the firebase rules ?

This is a question that come up from this problem : [Firebase Chat save to private chats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50297409/firebase-chat-save-to-private-chats)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Security rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45237730/firebase-security-rule)

Answer (score 2):

That's quite simple:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": { 
      "profile": {
        "chat": {
          ".read": "auth != null"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I highly recommend spending some time in the [Firebase security documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) before continuing, as this is likely to be one of the simpler use-cases, and pretty close to one of the [introductory sample rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart#sample-rules).